# Facing build issue after upgrade of react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts, craco

After upgrading react-scripts to version 5, i am facing build issue. Some files are missing after running build command. Sharing before and after screen shot of build command.

[image: Before Upgrade]

[image: After Upgrade]

Also using **craco** latest version for configuration.

After creating build *main.[hash].chunk.js*, *main.[hash].chunk.css* & *runtime-main.[hash].js* files are missing from build folder.

Craco config:

```
    const path = require('path');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = () => {
  const plugins = [];
  // if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  //   plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
  // }

  return {
    eslint: {
      enable: true,
    },
    style: {
      css: {
        loaderOptions: (cssLoaderOptions, { env, paths }) => {
          cssLoaderOptions.modules = {
            localIdentName: "[local]_[hash:base64:5]",
          };
          return cssLoaderOptions;
        },
      },
    },
    webpack: {
      alias: {
        react: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules', 'react'),
        'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules', 'react-dom'),
        'modernizr': path.resolve(__dirname, "./.modernizrrc.js")
      },
      plugins,
      configure: webpackConfig => {
        webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
          fs: false,
          path: require.resolve("path-browserify")
        };
        const scopePluginIndex = webpackConfig.resolve.plugins.findIndex(
          ({ constructor }) => constructor && constructor.name === 'ModuleScopePlugin'
        );
        webpackConfig.optimization= {
          chunkIds: 'natural',
        };        
        
        const [clientSrc] = webpackConfig.resolve.plugins[scopePluginIndex].appSrcs;
        const services = path.resolve(clientSrc, '../..');

        webpackConfig.resolve.plugins[scopePluginIndex].appSrcs.push(services);

        return webpackConfig;
      }
    },
    devServer: (devServerConfig, { env, paths, proxy, allowedHost }) => {
      devServerConfig = {
        server: {
          type: 'https'
        },
        https: undefined,
        onBeforeSetupMiddleware: undefined,
        onAfterSetupMiddleware: undefined
      };
      
      return devServerConfig;
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: could you please share your configuration file?

Comment: Sure, shared above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false in your build script? This will remove the need of a runtime-chunk file by embedding the code into the newly build index.html file instead.

If the newly built index.html runs then it is not an issue

Comment: Yes it's already set to false